# How to add "Process" column to Fiddler 4?

Tags: fiddler

I have been using Fiddler 4 on a laptop to debug web traffic for a while and have been using the Process column to identify stuff.  Great tool makes my life much easier.

But the problem is when I install fiddler 4 on the pc it doesn't have the "process" column.

How do I add it?  I have been through all the drop downs for Customize Columns>>Collections but cant find anything relating to process id.

The documentation seems to be sparse so I'm presuming its something obvious I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler's `Process` column is a built-in column that cannot be removed. The simplest way to ensure that you can see it (so that it's wider than 0 pixels) is to hold the `SHIFT` key while Fiddler is starting and accept the prompt to restore the default UI.